Grothendieck Duality involving Ext and Hom sheaves
I am currently trying to understand the general idea of the proof of a theorem that I have been using as a black box for quite some time now. Here is the set-up of the proof, given in my own words. I give references at the end.

Say we are given a smooth planar projective complex curve $C = V(f)$ of degree $2d$ and a matrix $M$ of size $d \times d$, its entries being homogeneous polynomials of degree $2$ satsifying $f = \det(M)$. Then $M$ induces an injective morphism of sheaves (and therefore a short exact sequence)
\begin{equation}
 0 \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-2) \overset{M}{\to} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2} \to \mathcal{F} \to 0.
\end{equation}
Here $\mathcal{F}$ is the cokernel and it is a coherent sheaf supported on $C$. On $C$ it is even a line bundle.
The transpose of $M$ analogously defines a short exact sequence
\begin{equation}
 0 \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-2) \overset{M^t}{\to} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2} \to \mathcal{G} \to 0.
\end{equation}

It is next claimed that $\mathcal{G} \cong \mathscr{E}xt_{\mathbb{P}^2}^1(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2})(-2) \cong \mathcal{F}^\vee(d-2)$ (where $\mathcal{F}^\vee$ is the dual sheaf of $\mathcal{F}$).
While I do not have full understanding of it, I am happy with the first isomorphism: My thinking is that passing from $M$ to $M^t$ corresponds to dualizing the short exact sequence (using the functor $\mathscr{H}om(-,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-2))$, and hence in the long exact sequence of cohomology the first Ext sheaf occurs (see for example Proposition 6.4 in Hartshorne).
My issue is with the second isomorphism. One of my sources claims that this is an application of Grothendieck duality. This is a concept I am not familiar with at all. What I have found online seems much more abstract (involving functors that I do not know and/or invoking higher direct images) than what I have at hand. In particular, I have not seen a single statement like: "Grothendieck duality relates Ext sheaves and Hom sheaves in the following way: [...]" Is there a way to motivate this isomorphism by other means, or reformulate abstract versions of Grothendieck duality in this specific setting?

Finally my references for the theorem:

The discussion at the beginning of section 6.2.1 (Quadratic determinantal representations) in Igor V. Dolgachev: Classical Algebraic Geometry, 2012.
The proof of Theorem B in Arnaud Beauville: Determinantal Hypersurfaces, Michigan Mathematical Journal 48, 2000, pp. 39-64.

